# C++ structs Interdependency

Tags: c++, syntax, struct

Hello i have structures declared in the same Header file that need eachother.

```
struct A; // ignored by the compiler
struct B{
  A _iNeedA; //Compiler error Here
};

struct A { 
  B _iNeedB;
};
```

this work normally

```
class A;
class B{
  A _iNeedA;
};

class A { 
  B _iNeedB;
    };

// everything is good
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you use classes it works, when you use structs it doesn't? If so, which compiler are you using?

Comment: This can not work even if you replace the struct keyword with class. Both are the same thing in C++ anyway. Other than that, I'd go with Rudolph's answer, except you can also use references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

the fact is what im doing is not exactly what i posted but i thougt it was the same thing, actually i'm using operators that take arguments. Thoses operators body must be defined after my structs declarations (outside the struct),
because struct B don't know yet struct A members...

I said it was working with classes because with classes we usualy use CPP file for methods definition, here i am not using any cpp file for methods i use in my structs

I was about to delete this post but you guys are too fast ;),

Here an example

```
struct A; 

struct B { 
int member;
bool operator<(const A& right); //body not defined

}; 

struct A { 

int member;
   bool operator<(const B& right)
   {
      return  this->member < B.member;
   }
}; 

 bool B::operator<(const A& right) //define the body here after struct A definition
{
    return  this->member < A.member;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This can’t work: `A` contains `B` contains `A` contains `B` contains …. Where to stop?

All you can do to model cyclic dependencies is use pointers:

```
class A;

class B {
    A* _iNeedA;
};

class A {
    B* _iNeedB;
};
```

Now the classes don’t contain each other, merely references to each other.

Furthermore, you need to pay attention that you can’t use things you haven’t *defined* yet: in the above code, you have *declared* `A` before defining `B`. So it’s fine to declare *pointers* to `A` in `B`. But you cannot yet *use* `A` before defining it.